# OS X El Capitan - Can't install bundler using gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler, osx-elcapitan

I just installed El Capitan and had to install rails. I am trying to install bundler but am getting the following error. I found this answer on stackexchange but seems like i would be messing with a security issue https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/204312/cant-install-bundler-using-gem

```
sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
```

update:

```
$ rvm gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc` or `rvm all do gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
$ gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Fetching: bundler-1.10.6.gem (100%)
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::FilePermissionError)
    You don't have write permissions for the /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0 directory.
$ sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Password:
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
$ rvm all do gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
$ bundle
zsh: command not found: bundle
$ sudo gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EPERM)
    Operation not permitted - /usr/bin/bundle
$ rvm gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc
Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc` or `rvm all do gem install bundler --no-ri --no-rdoc` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
$ rvm gem install bundle --no-ri --no-rdoc
Please note that `rvm gem ...` was removed, try `gem install bundle --no-ri --no-rdoc` or `rvm all do gem install bundle --no-ri --no-rdoc` instead. ( see: 'rvm usage' )
```

Answer (score 2):

You are probably running into El Capitan's new feature [System Integrity Protection](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/193368/what-is-the-rootless-feature-in-el-capitan-really).

However, you don't really want to install your gems and stuff for development in your system ruby.  I did that for many years, but really, save yourself the headaches and use [RVM](https://rvm.io) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Comment: From the errors, it looks like you are still using system ruby.  See https://rvm.io/rvm/basics to see how to install a ruby with rvm, make it current, create a gemset, etc.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/bundler/bundler/issues/4065

You'll need to either change your GEM_HOME or do

```
sudo gem install bundler -n /usr/local/bin
```

because of El Cap's introduction of SIP (System Integrity Protection).

Answer (score 0):

OS X 10.11 has a so-called "rootless" feature, which forbidden users to modify `/usr` directory. The only exception is `/usr/local`. So `sudo` is useless here. I suggest using `rbenv` to install a new ruby installation somewhere else.